# How can I make sure my system uses the ~/.screenrc file?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen

My friend provided me with a rather detailed `.screenrc` which I put into my `~/` directory. I am pretty confident when I run `screen` it isn't utilizing the edits in the file.

- How could I confirm whether I'm using it or not?
- How can I make sure my system uses the `~/.screenrc` file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$HOME/.screenrc should be the compiled-in default. You can also specify it on the command-line:

```
$ screen -c ~/.screenrc
```

You can also set it with an environment variable:

```
$ export SCREENRC="~/.screenrc"
```

As for confirming that it's being read/used, try putting these two into your screenrc:

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
```

If it comes up listing all of your windows on the bottom line, your screenrc is being read.

Answer (score 7):

[Brightlancer](https://superuser.com/questions/324310/how-can-i-make-sure-my-system-uses-the-screenrc-file/324573#324573)'s answer is useful, but based on some limited experience I can add:

**If there is an error in your .screenrc file, it appears that `screen` ignores the file silently.**

This could explain the cause. You may like to start with an empty file and add the lines slowly to find out the offending lines.

Answer (score 0):

The screenrc file doesn't take effect until you log in next time.  If you have created the file, and then run screen, it appears not to work.  However the next time you log in a bash session, it will work.

In the meantime, you can specify the file as per the other answer.  I find it easier just to quickly log in again.

Comment: that's not the case. try editing `.screenrc` with `echo hi` and you will see it works every time a screen is entered and left. It might be that there must not exist another screen session.