# What is the default password of gnu screen?

Tags: linux, bash, display

When I type *Ctrl-X X* (sic) in *screen*, the session is locked. What is the default password? Is it the same password which I use to log in to linux?

I ask because: I connect to several different remote linux servers via ssh, under various flavours of linux/unix, and have *screen* sessions running on all of them. When I lock the screen session and type my password, sometimes it works and on other installations it does not work and I therefore don't know what the password is (so I have to "quit" that screen session externally).

So, what is the default password of screen?

P.S.: I am never root. Version of screen used: Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Comment: I expect it depends on whether screen is in a login shell, and whether login is enabled for screen

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The screen password has always been simply the system password of the user running it in my experience.
the [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) says that if there's a screen lock program available, it will be used if configured so. So maybe you would need to figure out if this is the case, and how that program behaves.

Comment: For how to configure a custom lock program, see also http://serverfault.com/a/639406

Comment: And what if the user has no password and you use an SSH key to login?

Comment: I think then the user should not lock his screen; he might not be able to login again afterwards...

Comment: @jpjacobs: Alas, It's not always the user's choice: http://superuser.com/questions/344301/unexpected-behaviour-of-ctrl-a-x-and-ctrl-a-x-in-screen-regions-locking?rq=1

Comment: @Cerin: Open a new SSH connection and steal the screen session from yourself.

Comment: So this is a good answer, however does anyone know what you might do in a slurm environment when logging into the compute nodes directly is not possible?

Comment: i dont lock my screen, i accidentally press CTRL-A X, instead of CTRL-A Shift-X i think, when closing a pane, and always face this issue. and Yes, what about when using an SSH key which is my case?

Answer (score 40):

I sometimes find myself in the same situation, on servers where I have SSH public-key login and thus no password at all (that I know), and struggle to remember what I did last time to recover.

There is no need to kill the screen.  Just disconnect the terminal you are running `screen` in, then open a new terminal window and reattach (`screen -r`).

Maybe as a precaution, add `bind x` to your `.screenrc` so that the lock keystroke is unbound.  In an already running `screen`, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> `bind x`.

Comment: I tried adding this to my ~/.screenrc but it didn't seem to work. [If there is an error in your .screenrc file, it appears that screen ignores the file silently](https://superuser.com/a/331958/264276). [zodiac's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1286117/264276) worked though.

Comment: wouldnt that also unbind the key used for closing panes, which is one of main reasons i use screen?

Comment: @BrianThomas I'm not sure why you think that? Ctrl-A x is only used to lock the screen as far as I am aware.

Comment: @jozxyqk I'm not sure what error you are referring to; the guidance here seems identical to the guidance in the other answer you are linking to.

Answer (score 3):

the password of the user that owns the screen process.

Comment: What do you do when there is no password? I use a passwordless SSH key to login to my server and screen still asks me for a password...

Comment: using a phrase-less ssh key (bad idea btw, look into ssh-agent) isn't the same as having no password. screen will want whatever the users password is on the remote system in /etc/shadow

Answer (score 3):

After trying many approaches, I found that:

- The BEST solution is adding two lines

  `bind x
  bind ^x`

  to your `.screenrc` file.

(**Note** If you are not root user, remember to add `alias screen="screen -C [your .screenrc file path]"` to your `.bashrc` file)

- The second BEST solution is adding one line

  `export LOCKPRG='/bin/true'`

  to your `.bashrc` file. However, this method is somewhat uncommon, refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175405/what-is-bin-true)

At last, thanks a lot to this guy [disabling_gnu_screen_lock_screen](https://www.pantz.org/software/screen/disabling_gnu_screen_lock_screen.html), I just copy-paste his content here.

Comment: You don't need the `-C` option unless you save the `.screenrc` in a nonstandard place, i.e. not in your home directory.