# unexpected behaviour of Ctrl-a x and Ctrl-a X in screen?! regions, locking

Tags: linux, bash, display

According to the *screen* manual (version 4.0.2.)

```
C-a x
C-a C-x     (lockscreen)  Lock this terminal.
C-a X       (remove)      Kill the current region.
```

But what actually happens when I use it (Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06):

```
C-a X   locks the terminal and asks me for the password. When I enter the correct passwword, I am back in screen but the region is killed (wtf)
C-a x   does nothing apparently
```

Please note the differences between x (lowercase) and X (uppercase).

Why is there a mixup between the functionalities of *C-a X* and *C-a x*? How can I fix this?

I am on *CentOS release 5 (Final)*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your screenrc (personal or system wide) has changed these bindings from the defaults.

To see what they're currently set to, view the bindings by hitting the "help" combo -- <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>.

See if the entries for `lockscreen` and `remove` match what the man page says.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the case mixup.

But I'm assuming that the 'Kill the current region' does nothing because you only use one region.

Start another region using <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (horizontal split) or <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> (vertical split, only on recent versions of screen).

*Now* you can use <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to kill a region, or <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to keep only the currently active region (similar to <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd> and re-attach with `screen -DR` -- resetting the region layout)

Comment: "> But I'm assuming that the 'Kill the current region' does nothing because you only use one region." But I *did* create a new region before doing Ctrl-a X!

Comment: @gojira: sry, no need to be shouting. You didn't say it, and it is not uncommon for users of screen to confuse windows and regions

Comment: I am not shouting, I just clarified that I already had a region open which I thought was implied, but probably I was not clear enough. So yes, the region is open it's just that the functionalities of C-a X and C-a x are mixed up. Would be happy if someone knows the reason or a solution. Thanks.